Go install, but repo and module declared are not a match
I was given access to a private repo on Github that is actually some cli tool written in Golang. I tried installing it like this:
go install github.com/company-x/afctl@latest

Which resulted in an error:
github.com/company-x/afctl@v1.0.0: parsing go.mod:
module declares its path as: company-y.io/afctl
        but was required as: github.com/company-x/afctl

Which is expected because module is declared as
module company-y.io/afctl

go 1.14
…

I presume they used to host the repo some place else before moving it to Github. I guess there’s no way then to install it using ‘go install’? They’re probably not going to let me tinker with their source code. I just want to make sure I haven't missed something.

You could try go install company-y.io/afctl@latest, when https://company-y.io/afctl is reachable.
Otherwise do
git clone -b v1.0.0 https://github.com/company-x/afctl.git
cd afctl
go install .


'go install .' does the job, thanks
